# Sucess and Error Message is not shown on Contact Form

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento version 2.4, When i submit the contact Form it not shown Error or success message.Mail For contact form is working properly.

Please Let me know the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you check console wether you are getting js error or not

Comment: No I cant getting any error.

Comment: But when I add a alert in execute function just for checking. I am getting error.

Comment: 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php:94) in /home/stagingclearance/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148 Exception #0 (Exception):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message block must be missing,add this block in Magento_Theme Default Layout file:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml"/>
        <container name="page.messages" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page messages">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```